# Computing determinant of matrix - confused with solution

Tags: matrices, determinant

Given that 
$$\begin{vmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i\end{vmatrix}=9$$

Compute
\begin{vmatrix}a&b&c\\4g&4h&4i\\d+2a&e+2b&f+2c\end{vmatrix}

I have the solution my teacher made below but I'm having trouble understanding how he got the values in front of each matrix (which I highlighted). Like why does $4$ eventually turn into $-4$? I don't understand where he's pulling these values from and I'd appreciate it if someone explained.

\begin{align}
\begin{vmatrix}a&b&c\\4g&4h&4i\\d+2a&e+2b&f+2c\end{vmatrix}\hspace{4mm}&\vcenter{\underrightarrow{R_2\leftarrow{\textstyle{\frac{1}{4}}}R_2}}\hspace{4mm}\bbox[yellow,3px]4\begin{vmatrix}a&b&c\\g&h&i\\d+2a&e+2b&f+2c\end{vmatrix} \\[2ex]
&\vcenter{\underrightarrow{R_3\leftarrow R_3-2R_1}}\hspace{4mm}\bbox[yellow,3px]4\begin{vmatrix}a&b&c\\g&h&i\\d&e&f\end{vmatrix} \\[2ex]
&\vcenter{\underrightarrow{R_2\leftrightarrow R_3}}\hspace{3mm}\bbox[yellow,3px]{-4}\begin{vmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i\end{vmatrix}=-4\cdot9=-36
\end{align}

Comment: These are basic properties of determinants. Multiplying any one row or column by a constant multiplies the value of the determinant by that constant. Interchanging any two rows or any two columns results in $-1$ being multiplied to the value of the determinant.

Comment: Multiplying a row in a matrix multiplies the determinant by the same amount. Swapping rows changes the sign of the determinant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to know how elementary row operations affect the determinant:

- If two rows are swapped, the determinant changes sign i.e. is multiplied by $-1$
- If a row is multiplied by a constant $c$, then so is the determinant
- If a multiple of one row is added to another, the determinant is unaffected

We are given that your matrix has determinant $9$. Notice that the matrix in question is obtained from your original matrix as follows:

- Multiply the third row by $4$ (so multiply determinant by $4$ to get $36$)
- Add twice row $1$ to row $2$ (no effect on determinant)
- Swap the second and third rows (multiply determinant by $-1$ to get $-36$)